# Open android app when clicking in an Azure Reach push notification

Tags: android, azure-mobile-engagement

I'm trying to open an Android app when clicking in an Azure reach push. System and In-app notifications are arriving to devices correctly but when I click it nothing happens.

I've followed this documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-engagement-android-integrate-engagement-reach/ and after some research I've noticed that my EngagementReachDataPushReceiver extended class (with the overriden methods "onDataPushStringREcieved" and "onDataPushBase64Received") never get called.

Of course I've added the reference in the Android manifest to that class so... Someone have any clue about what can be happening?

Answer (score 1):

this question is already taken care of on the official MSDN forum, I see you also posted there: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bc993cf-66a5-47d9-8778-528661913417/my-engagementreachdatapushreceiver-extended-class-doesnt-get-called?forum=azuremobileengagement

Comment: Yeah, I also asked in official forum but no, at the moment the answer is not solving the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I've found the solution on my own. The problem was in the `onNotificationPrepared` overriden method, specifically the way I was building the notification:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
```

The notification builder needs to be:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
```

*(from android.support.v7.app)*

And magically the received pushes started to open the app again.